# Passing a two dimensional array, Works in C but not C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I am passing a two dimensional array to the mark function.

```
void mark(int n, int m, int i, int j, int canvisit[][m], int a[][m]){}
```

this code is working perfectly in C on Codeblocks but in C++, I am getting errors like :

```
prog.cpp:9:55: error: use of parameter outside function body before ']' token
 void mark(int n, int m, int i, int j, int canvisit[][m], int a[][m]){
                                                       ^
prog.cpp:9:56: error: expected ')' before ',' token
 void mark(int n, int m, int i, int j, int canvisit[][m], int a[][m]){
                                                        ^
prog.cpp:9:58: error: expected unqualified-id before 'int'
 void mark(int n, int m, int i, int j, int canvisit[][m], int a[][m]){
```

Am I doing something wrong here? I am giving the number of columns before by `int m` , and this is working in C but not C++. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array arguments you declare are [*variable-length arrays*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) and those are not allowed in C++. You have to solve in in other ways, like using templates, `std::vector` or `std::array`.

Remember that C and C++ are two very different languages. C++ may have been originally developed from C, and they share syntax for many things, but they are still different languages with different rules.

Answer (score 2):

Only C supports variable length arrays, C++ doesn't. C++ standard says that the size of the array must be a constant expression.

Use `std::vector` instead. Declaration should be

```
void mark(int n, int m, int i, int j, vector< vector<int> > &canvisit, vector< vector<int> > &a);
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please tell me then how I should approach my problem ?

Comment: As stated, C has some (very few) new constructs that are not supported by C++. Originally, ANSI C 89 is very close to a true subset of C++. For example, in the K&R book (ANSI version) all examples compile with a C++ compiler too.

Since C99, the languages have diverged somewhat. In C++, you use std::vector as the main workhorse, sometimes you can use std::array for fixed-length arrays. In general, use the STL (vector, map, list, algorithms, iterators...) it is an amazingly fast and versatile part of the standard library!

Comment: @tarunkt; Edited the answer.